# Alternative of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core in dot net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core

Can you please help me to find out Alternative of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core in dot net core 3.1

I wants it because i want Below Methods in dot net core 3.1

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Properties.Add(System.Web.Http.Hosting.HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration());
```

But here it Shows an Error that System.Web.Http.Hosting is not available. System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration is Not available.

As a further Information i have already Referenced Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim Package.

Can you please help me to get rid of this I have spent much time to find out solution of this.

Thanks in advance.